# Python pip install error

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have just installed Python 3.4.3 on my MAC (Yosemite). I need to install a couple of lxml, however everytime I type in: pip install /""/, I get error messages.
I have followed multiple tutorials and pip is installed.
MAC already had Python 2.7., but I installed the 3.4.3. version, not sure if that is the issue.
The error message is:

> Brunos-MacBook-Pro:~ BrunoPaesLeme$ pip install /Macintosh HD/Users//Downloads/pycairo-1.10.0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
>   Exception:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 223, in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 268, in run
>       wheel_cache
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 268, in populate_requirement_set
>       wheel_cache=wheel_cache
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 207, in from_line
>       wheel_cache=wheel_cache)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 66, in **init**
>       req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(req)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 2960, in parse
>       reqs = list(parse_requirements(s))
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 2891, in parse_requirements
>       raise ValueError("Missing distribution spec", line)
>   ValueError: ('Missing distribution spec', '/Macintosh')

Anybody knows what I could be doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
easy_install pip
pip install /"filepath"/
```

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue with pip install. However, if I do "sudo su -" then do my pip install 'fileName', that solve the problem for me.